# How to remove li space after hiding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

How to hide `li` , and remove it's space.
The following code is to transfer between images,but when hiding the previous `li` it's empty space appears .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedIndex = 1;
        $("#slide" + selectedIndex + " img").fadeIn(500);
        $("ul.captios li").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
            $("#slide" + selectedIndex + " img").fadeOut(500, function () {
                $("#slide" + id + " img").fadeIn(500);
                $("#slide" + selectedIndex).css("display:none;");
                selectedIndex = id;
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

a html

```
 <div id="gal-container">
        <div id="slides-wrapper">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li id="slide1"><img  class="hide" src="imgs/img1.jpg" /></li>
                <li id="slide2"><img  class="hide" src="imgs/img2.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="caption-wrapper">
           <ul class="captios">
                <li id="caption_1"><a href="#">img1</a></li>
                <li id="caption_2"><a href="#">img2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is slide id present on your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
        $("#slide" + selectedIndex).hide();
```

??

Or even better might be:

```
 $("#slide" + selectedIndex).fadeOut(500, function () {
      $("#slide" + id).fadeIn(500);
      selectedIndex = id;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.css()` incorrectly. You can pass it a single string, which is the name of a CSS property, and it will act as a 'getter', returning the value for that property.

Or you can pass it two strings, the name of a CSS property and a value, which will act as a 'setter', setting that property to have that value.

So, rather than `$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css("display:none;");` you want `$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css("display", "none");`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code. Change

$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css("display:none;");

to

$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css({display: 'none'}); or $("#slide" + selectedIndex).css('display', 'none');

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the css part wrong:

```
$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css("display:none;"); // It will return the css 
                                                  //definition for display:none
```

Use this instead:

```
$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css('display', 'none')
```

or the `hide` function which does exactly the same thing out of the box:

```
$("#slide" + selectedIndex).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is your problem, but...this line is not correct:

```
$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css("display:none;");
```

It should be:

```
$("#slide" + selectedIndex).css('display', 'none');
// OR
$("#slide" + selectedIndex).hide();
```